# Repeat background image - no crop or make it symmetric

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

What I want:
[image]
What I want (crop first one, too, but keep symmetry):
[image]
What I have:
[image]

```
div.row.separator div.col {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url("./images/rhomb.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

rhomb.png:
[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Title here 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
      luctus eros at maximus tincidunt. Donec fringilla mattis massa,
      vitae blandit massa egestas sed. Maecenas ipsum ligula, pretium
      nec pellentesque convallis, consequat at magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row separator">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
  </div>
  .......
```

Body is gray, container is white. I want a line of rhombs after a section as separator.

So, having a small image used as background repeat-x in a div is it possible to prevent crop on last one or make the same crop on first one (align center the repetitive background...)?

UPDATE: Feel free to experiment: https://github.com/GhitaB/sample-design-bootstrap4-css (I'm just curious. Not a real problem for me.)

Comment: Generally, you have set fixed width and this width is multiple value of the image width.

Comment: Yes, in this case I prefer changing the image with a ok-to-be-cropped one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though **space** in background-repeat is still poorly supported, the twin property in border-image has a good support (starting in IE11)

```css
.test {
  height: 0px;
  width: 182px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 38px;
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aOpi.png) 0 0 38 0 space;
}

.test:nth-child(2) {
  width: 210px;
}

.test:nth-child(3) {
  width: 220px;
}
.test:nth-child(4) {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Haha. This is exactly what I wanted to have. You are great. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing:

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

with

```
background-repeat: space;
```

seems to solve my problem. (Not 100%, but in almost all cases)

> space: tile the image in both directions. Never crop the image unless a single image is too large to fit. If multiple images can fit, space them out evently images always touching the edges.
>   (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-repeat/)

Also: https://www.impressivewebs.com/space-round-css3-background/

Comment: Good on Google Chrome. Sadly, Firefox takes care about first and last one but sometimes the other images are in random places - worse than initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when it comes to the background, sadly, we aren't able to resize images expressly. We can fill the whole page or keep the pictures original image. My idea for this would be to create multiples of the image your self using a picture editing software and then add the repeated image in the full screen format.

Comment: Good idea, but what about responsivity? To be used multiple images for multiple screen sizes?

Comment: That's the work of bootstrap. Just be sure the body is in a .container-fluid and the background is for the body. That way, if it is opened in a mobile or tablet, it would respond and still fill the screen while maintaining your design.

Comment: No, the background image need to be set for a row + col because it is used as a separator for content sections. Take a look, please: https://ghitab.github.io/sample-design-bootstrap4-css/

Comment: Making it as a single image the height of the separator will be different from a screen to other.